# Since when can spring use cglib for proxy creation?

Tags: java, spring

I'm looking for the date (month and year), and optionally the version, since when Spring can use cglib or javassist for creating proxy, and doesn't need interfaces anymore for proxyfied beans.

Does someone remember it ?

Comment: Out of curiosity – why?

Comment: I would say from pretty early versions... if not from the beginning.

Comment: Why ? out of curiosity yes, and for a blog post I'm writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The oldest changelog](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.0.0/changelog.txt) on [docs.spring.io](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/) show that Spring 1.0.0, in 11/2003, includes cglib proxies:

```
Changes in version 1.0 M3 (25.11.2003)
--------------------------------------

Package org.springframework.aop
* major AOP API changes: see changes-M2-M3.txt for further details
* added "targetClass" argument to StaticMethodPointcut.applies()
* CGLIB proxies support introductions now
* can force CGLIB proxying using new "proxyTargetClass" property on DefaultProxyConfig
* introduced various invoker interceptors like Prototype-, CommonsPooling-, and ThreadLocalInvokerInterceptor
```

I couldn't find the referenced changes-M2-M3.txt file, but this hints that cglib proxies were added in M3.

Comment: Actually if you read the file you will notice that it was introduced in 0.9.1 released on 8-8-2003...

Comment: @M.Deinum you're right! Would you mind editing my post? (Sorry - have to run)